# flutter_login additionalSignupFields does not work

Tags: flutter, dart

I struggle with adding new signup fields. I tried it on web and macos platform.
[flutter_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login) version is 4.2.1, Dart 3.0.5

The login features work as expected, but when I want to extend the signup form with additional fields, it does not work. It does not show up.

```dart
class LoginView extends StatelessWidget {

  static const String route = "login";

  const LoginView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<LoginViewModel>.reactive(
        viewModelBuilder: () => LoginViewModel(),
      builder: (context, model, _) =>
          FlutterLogin(
            title: 'whatever',
            logo: const AssetImage('assets/images/ecorp-lightblue.png'),
            onLogin: model.authUser,
            onSignup: model.signupUser,
            additionalSignupFields: const [
              //It does not want to show up this field
              UserFormField(
                keyName: 'Username',
                icon: Icon(Icons.abc)
              )
            ],
            onSubmitAnimationCompleted: () => context.go('/${HomeView.route}'),
            onRecoverPassword: model.recoverPassword,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

It seems like a bug, but can someone see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it works like the [documentation mentions](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_login/latest/flutter_login/FlutterLogin-class.html) "By setting this, after signup another card with a form for additional user data is shown", thus the additional signup fields show up when you successfully set the email and password during sign up.

The default signup screen looks like this:
[image: default signup screen]

The second screen looks as follows:
[image: Additional fields]

It was slightly confusing because I expected the additional field on the first screen.